# Modifying text in Python

Tags: python

**Currently, I have text imported below.**

```
AS400 Storage Management -svc
AS400 Storage Management -svc 2
AS400 Hardware Management -sv 2
AS400 HA sync -app
AS400 HA sync -svc
Bank Users to Cognos
FTP to AS400
```

**I need to modify it to look like this using Python:**

```
(name eq 'AS400 Storage Managemnet -svc'
or name eq 'AS400 Storage Management -svc 2'
or name eq 'AS400 Hardware Management -sv 2'
or name eq 'AS400 HA sync -app'
or name eq 'AS400 HA sync -svc'
or name eq 'Bank Users to Cognos'
or name eq 'FTP to AS400'
```

**My python script is:**

```py
fwtext = []
with open("C:/Users/me/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/paloalto/TestText.txt") as f:
    line = f.readline()
    while line:
        line = f.readline()
        fwtext.append(line)
        print("(name eq "+line+"")


with open("C:/Users/me/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/paloalto/fwsearch.txt", "w")as f:
        for line in fwtext:
            f.write("name eq '"+line+"'or ")
```

Which displays below. How do I get Python to manipulate my text to include "(" beginning of the text and ")" at the eof? I've tried so many different ways to do this and I am new to Python.

```
name eq 'AS400 Storage Management -svc 2
'or name eq 'AS400 Hardware Management -sv 2
'or name eq 'AS400 HA sync -app
'or name eq 'AS400 HA sync -svc
'or name eq 'Bank Users to Cognos
'or name eq 'FTP to AS400
```

Answer (score 0):

These kind of changes can be easily done by the core [**re**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) library.

You can also invoke a function to do custom replacements.

Use [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub)

> If *`repl`* is a function, it is called for every non-overlapping occurrence of *`pattern`*. The function takes a single match object argument, and returns the replacement string.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a package, `re` is probably your best bet as the above person said. If you want to code it from scratch, I think it would be easiest to think of the whole input as one big block of `\n`-separated text and then using some basic string operations:

```
with open("file_out.txt", "w") as f_out:
    with open("file_in.txt", "r") as f_in:
        data = f_in.read().split("\n")           # get list of all lines
        data = [f"name eq '{v}'" for v in data]  # add the name component to all
        data = "\nor ".join(data)                # join them by 'or ' string
        f_out.write(f"({data})")                 # write out the result in parens
```

Comment: You don't need to open one more `with` block, just list two `open()` in single `with` separated by coma. Also take a look on [`str.splitlines()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines).

Comment: I'm gonna stick by my choice here to horizontally condense the code. It's good to mention that, though. The proposal is to do `with open(...) as f_out, open(...) as f_in`

Comment: It's not forbidden to start each `open()` from new line ;-)